# A class Exception do PHP para o sistema?

Tags: php, exceção

Uma dúvida que me surgiu a pouco é **"A class Exception do PHP para o sistema?"**, o quero dizer é, quando lançamos uma exceção no script, algo depois desta exceção continua em funcionamento?

Comment: Desculpe, mas dúvida não ficou clara

Comment: O quero dizer é, preciso utilizar o `die()` após lançar uma exceção para matar o sistema? ou não é necessário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá!

De acordo com [a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php) não:

> Quando uma exceção é disparada, código logo após à instrução não será
> executada, e o PHP tentará achar o primeiro bloco catch correspondente
> à exceção disparada. Se uma exceção não for pega, um Erro Fatal do PHP
> será lançado com uma mensagem "Uncaught Exception ...", a não ser que
> um tratador tenha sido definido com set_exception_handler().

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa que algo seja executado mesmo se houver uma exceção, você precisar usar o "finally".

exemplo:

```
// O codigo abaixo vai imprimir: 1234
echo '1';
try {
    echo '2';
    throw new Exception();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '3';
} finally {
    echo '4';
}
```

Link de referência: http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/try-catch-finally-exception-em-php.html